# How do I output the contents of a specific row from a CSV file?

Tags: java, excel, csv, replace, cell

The goal of my code is to ask the user for an input, and my code will search my CSV file and output the correct row and column the data lies. However, I'm quite stumped as to how to extract that specific cell so I can then edit the contents.

Say I search for `banana` and my code searches for `banana` and then outputs that specific row which will include `banana,store` to a variable so I can then edit the location, and put it back in the correct cell.

Here's the code for finding the row and column of the specific text I search for:

```
try{

        String strSearch = searchSerialField.getText();

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("test.txt"), ',');
        List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
        reader.close();

        for (int row = 0; row < myEntries.size(); row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < myEntries.get(row).length; column++)
            {
                if (myEntries.get(row)[column].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(strSearch))
                {
                    System.out.println("Found - Your item is on row: " + row + ", column: " + column);
                }
            }
        }

//I now need to output the contents of the row into something so I can edit it
```

I'm now just needing to extract the row into something so I can then edit the location, but I'm clueless as to how I should be approaching this?

If anyone has any tips or methods I should be following, then that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do the edits come from?  You say you want to change the cell, but I don't see what you want to change it to.

Comment: You can store the file in 2D array if its small, from the 2D array you can get the position using index

Comment: @DrewWills I want to change the location, as specified in the description. Another form will be opened so I can change the location, but for this specific question, I'm wanting to know how I can extract the row into something which I can then edit.

Answer (score 0):

Java `String`s are immutable;  you can't change them, you have to create new ones.  `List`s and arrays, on the other hand are mutable (unless they're not).

You can do...

```
for (int row = 0; row < myEntries.size(); row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < myEntries.get(row).length; column++)
    {
        if (myEntries.get(row)[column].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(strSearch))
        {
            System.out.println("Found - Your item is on row: " + row + ", column: " + column);
            String myNewString = "something else";
            myEntries.get(row)[column] = myNewString;  // Replaces the String at this array index
        }
    }
}

// Now write the contents to a CSVWriter variable called 'myCSVWriter'
for (String[] entry : myEntries) {
    myCSVWriter.writeNext(entry);
}
myCSVWriter.close();

// Actually -- instead of that -- an easier way would be...
myCSVWriter.writeAll(myEntries);
myCSVWriter.close();
```

When you're done, you can use the `myEntries` collection to overwrite the contents of the file.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the help, but I'm a bit stuck on how to write back to the file. I have declared a CSVWriter variable, but what do I write to write the contents back to the file?

Comment: If you have a properly-constructed `CSVWriter `, you can call one (or more than one) of the `write*` methods, followed by `close()` when you're done.

Comment: `writer.writeNext(myEntries)` - Cannot convert List<String[]> to String[]. I tried `writer.writeNext(myEntries.toArray(new String[myEntries.size()]));` but it's throwing an error. How can I successfully get around this error?

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Now I just need to know how to display the extracted row so I know what to change the 'location' to. So if the extracted row displays the location of an item is in store, then I will change the location to home.